# append “%” in `<svg>` stop tag

Tags: angular, svg, attributes

Want to append “%” in `<svg>` stop tag.
For example, I tried below code but it is giving me an error.

```
<linearGradient 
  id="progress1019" 
  x1="0" 
  y1="1" 
  x2="0" 
  y2="0">
  <stop 
    id="stop1002" 
    [attr.offset]="enterMyData.itspendrev{{'%'}}" 
    stop-color="#02ABBA" />
  <stop 
    id="stop2002" 
    [attr.offset]="enterMyData.itspendrev{{'%'}}" 
    stop-color="#e1edf3" />
</linearGradient>
```

But unfortunately, it is giving me an error. I am using angular 6.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `enterMyData.itspendrev` is the property you want to append `%` to:

Try this:

```
<linearGradient 
  id="progress1019" 
  x1="0" 
  y1="1" 
  x2="0" 
  y2="0">
  <stop 
    id="stop1002" 
    [attr.offset]="enterMyData.itspendrev  + '%'" 
    stop-color="#02ABBA" />
  <stop 
    id="stop2002" 
    [attr.offset]="enterMyData.itspendrev + '%'" 
    stop-color="#e1edf3" />
</linearGradient>
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working as expected. One more doubt I have can you please help?

Comment: There are 2 svg, one is up arrow svg and second is down arrow svg.  I am able to fill up arrow from bottom but I can't fill down arrow from top.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want to achieve. Please consider creating a stackblitz or show some image or example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: You can see that down arrow is filling from down, it should be from top.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by filling from down?

Comment: That blue color should be from top in down arrow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179226/discussion-between-siddharth-ajmera-and-pathik-vejani).